# group middleware not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, api

I am create Restfull API using laravel 5.4 and create simple CRUD demo with middleware group routing. **Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api']** 
but it's not working.

my **routes/api.php** file is following

```
Use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');
    Route::get('articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@show');
    Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');
    Route::put('articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@update');
    Route::delete('articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@delete');
});
```

and my controller file **app\Http\Controller\ArticleController .php** is following
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Article::all();
    }

    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return $article;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 201);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
    {
        $article->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 200);
    }

    public function delete(Article $article)
    {
        $article->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
}
```

but it's not working.
please, give me some help full solution.

**controller\autth\loginController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            $user = $this->guard()->user();
            $user->generateToken();

            return response()->json([
                'data' => $user->toArray(),
            ]);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

        if ($user) {
            $user->api_token = null;
            $user->save();
        }

        return response()->json(['data' => 'User logged out.'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

and **auth\registroController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->generateToken();

        return response()->json(['data' => $user->toArray()], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my **user.php** model is following:

```
namespace App;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
// use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable; //, EntrustUserTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function index() {
        return User::all();
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function generateToken()
    {
        $this->api_token = str_random(60);
        $this->save();

        return $this->api_token;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions**; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152264/discussion-on-question-by-maulik-kanani-group-middleware-not-working-in-laravel). If you are asked for clarification or additional code, [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using resource route. i prefer simple code like this

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');

and add the middleware in controller

```
use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return Article::all();
    }

    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return $article;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 201);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
    {
        $article->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 200);
    }

    public function delete(Article $article)
    {
        $article->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
}
```